# What is the "tractor back"?

Tags: translation

I have this phrase and the context is the farming:

> I need somebody... who, during planting time and harvest season will
>   finish his 40-hour week by Tuesday noon and then, paining from tractor
>   back, put in another 72 hours.

I do not understand *paining from tractor back*, what does it mean? Is it referred to the rear part of the tractor? Or is it referred to the back pain of the driver of the tractor due to his tough job?

Full source is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMpZ0TGjbWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one.

*Paining* is used as an intransitive verb here, meaning *being in pain*. And "tractor back" is what is causing the pain. The idea is that the farmer already has a *sore back* ("tractor back") from planting and harvesting with a tractor the first forty hours, but nevertheless he needs to "put in" (work) another 72 hours--despite the pain.

Comment: The phrase "tractor back" is not common English, but many common constructs use that same form (such as _tennis elbow_, for one).